# What is a Singleton Variant

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, genomics

I'm reading a paper that on a population genetics study where they sequence a number of genomes. The study states that 101 *Singleton Variants* per individual where found. What does *Singleton* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) in mathematics is a set with one element.

They are likely referring to variants found in only one individual in their pool. It's possible there are other uses of the word singleton but given the context I think it is most likely.